# Atom IDE - Opens thousands of files when I add project folder

Tags: atom-editor

When I launch Atom IDE, everything is fine. The issue comes when I go to add a new project folder. The one I tried to add was simply a folder with a blank html file inside it. After adding it, the IDE becomes very slow and adds thousands of files to the right hand panel.

[image: Bottom right corner showing 80k+ files]

I have tried uploading a new folder, as well as a new file and receive the same result.

Comment: I noticed this issue goes away when I disable the github integration package.

Comment: If you're in a git repo, Atom will make the root of the repo the base of the current project. Presumably that is happening here and your git repo has 83k files in it.

Comment: how do I check/disable that?

Comment: You did, by disabling the GitHub package